# How to develop a video player that receives video stream on wi-fi broadcasting/multicasting?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, codec

general video players connect the media server through unicast 
but I need a player to receive media stream using multicast/broadcast.

scenario:
     Media Server ---> AP --(multicast/broadcast video stream)--> player(android phone)

is there any Android SDK to support this function?
or is there any solution without developing software codec and RTP stack?

James.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post about Android and multi-cast support: [How to receive Multicast packets on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179710/how-to-receive-multicast-packets-on-android)

The question about a multicast video streaming protocol is a separate issue.  There should be nothing Android-specific required (assuming you can get and receive multicast data is all you need from Android).

Getting the new codec to show up as a video-playing app in Android is a separate issue. See this question:
[How to add a new video codec to Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604619/how-to-add-a-new-video-codec-to-android)