# How to add a new video codec to Android?

Tags: android, video, codec

I have to add a custom video codec to Android that pulls in a video stream that contains metadata such as location, time, and graphic and textual annotations.  The information must be demuxed and then presented as a video with annotation overlays and also as a map (e.g. Google map) with annotations.  How can this be done?  I'm interested in any information, links, etc. that will get me closer.

Comment: It should be noted that I'm not very interested in how this *can't* be accomplished - I have to do it in some form or another, although perhaps I can do it in a different way than I'm thinking of.

Comment: Why use a codec?  Why not write your own code that accesses the data as a stream, performs the demux step, and the spits out the video portion of the content in a format that the built-in codecs can render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be good suggestions in this question:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting/browse_thread/thread/4b961fe43cb29b18

This may be more work than you are looking for, and may be more limiting than you desire.